# How to groupby and count binomial variable in python? and make a plot of this

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bigdata

i have a dataframe like this:

| country | question1 | question2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| france | yes | no |
| italy | yes | yes |
| france | yes | no |
| germany | no | yes |
| italy | no | yes |

i would like to get an output like a pivot table or a group with a count of yes/no for each Question and each country(similar countifs of excel).

I tried many methods as `df.groupby(country).value_counts()` or `df.groupby(country).sum("Yes")`

but i cannot get the result wanted.

And i would like to make a chart of this result obtained, only for the YES answer.

Someone can give me an advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How to groupby and count binomial variables?

We can **encode** the values in the columns `question1` and `question2` using [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) then `sum` the encoded values per unique `country` to get the counts of number of `Yes` and `No` for each question per `country`

```
counts = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('country')).sum(level=0)
```

---

```
         question1_no  question1_yes  question2_no  question2_yes
country                                                          
france              0              2             2              0
italy               1              1             0              2
germany             1              0             0              1
```

#### How to make a plot of this?

Filter the question columns containing `_Yes` suffixed in their names, then call the `plot` method of pandas dataframe with `kind=bar` to create a bar chart showing the counts of questions having `Yes` corresponding to each country

```
counts.filter(like='_yes').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]